# How can values transferred to Blender be changed to float type?

Tags: python, scripting, custom-properties

I transferred data from Matlab to Blender. The data is stored in the variables prop0-prop5 (6 variables in total)
The values I transferred are decimal, and when transferring the data to Blender I see that the numbers received in Blender are the correct numbers.
But why when I run the simulation\print the values, the numbers become int type?

Suppose the number I transferred is 7.239494, after printing I get 7

I would really appreciate the help! I'm really stuck on this.

[image]

Comment: how do you define/set the custom properties?

Comment: Blender stores values as 32 bit floats with no problems and they don't  just get randomly converted to integers unless you do that yourself. The issue must be in the way you transfer the values or the way you create the properties.

Comment: % MATLAB script - this is my matlab code:
a = [7.53535,5.422,8.999,10,322.333,6.77865]; 
% Set up a TCP/IP socket
host = 'localhost';
port =   12345;
tcp_client = tcpclient(host, port);
 for k=1:length(a)
    % Create example data
    example_data = a(k); % Send 6 variables to blender

    % Convert the example data to JSON format
    json_data = struct('custom_properties', example_data);
    json_string = jsonencode(json_data);

    % Send the JSON-formatted data to Blender
    write(tcp_client, json_string);
    pause(0.1)
 end

 % clear tcp_client;

Comment: Someone know how to solve it?